For a tree $T$ with $n$ vertices and $l$ leaves, show that $T$ has a path of at least length $\frac{2(n-1)}{l}$.
I'm currently trying to prove the following claim and was wondering if my proof is sufficient.
For a tree $T$ with $n$ vertices and $l$ leaves, show that $T$ has a path of at least length $\frac{2(n-1)}{l}$.
My proof attempt:
We will prove the statement by induction on the number of leaves $l$.
Base case:
Let $T$ be a tree on $n$ vertices with 2 leaves, then $T$ is simply a path of length $n-1$ from one leaf to the other.
Induction step:
Let $T$ be a tree on $n$ vertices with $l$ leaves. In order to add a leaf to $T$, we need to append a new vertex to a vertex in $T$ that isn't a leaf. By assumption, $T$ has path of at least length $\frac{2(n-1)}{l}$ and since
$$
\frac{2(n-1)}{l}-\frac{2n}{l+1} = \frac{2n -2l-2}{l(l+1)},
$$
and  $n > l \implies n \geq l+1$ hold, we get
$$
\frac{2n -2l-2}{l(l+1)} \geq 0.
$$
Thus $T$ with the newly appended leaf also satisfies the inequality, concluding the proof.
While writing my attempt, I wasn't sure if I needed to do induction on both $n$ and $l$ or if it was sufficient to only do induction on $l$. I would also be interested in knowing if there is a way of proving the statement without induction.
Any and all feedback is much appreciated!

For the induction step from a smaller tree $T$, consider also the case that a new leaf is added to an existing leaf. For example a bigger tree $T'$ with: one centre vertex $C$, connecting to $3$ or more branches each with one intermediate vertex and one leaf ($C - V - L$). Then removing any leaf from $T'$ to form $T$ would only keep the leaf number constant.

Induction needs to start with an arbitrary “$l+1$ object” and prove something about it. Anytime one starts from an “$l$ object”, as is done here, the possibility remains open that only certain “$l+1$ objects” arise from the construction in the proof.
For example, note that most trees with $3$ leaves do not arise from starting with the tree with $2$ leaves and then adding a third leaf.

I see the problem, thank you for the response. Is induction on $l$ the wrong approach to this problem? Because I don't see a way of doing the induction step by starting off with a tree with $l+1$ leaves.

I don't know how to prove the given statement.

You can prove this statement in two ways, I believe.
One is via induction, s.t in the induction step you delete all $\ell$ leafs of the graph instead of just one, I'll let you work out the details.
The other way it can be done, I think, is the following:
Take a path of maximal length $P$ in $T$ and take a midpoint vertex (e.g. in a $3$-vertex path the middle vertex $v$ and in a $4$-vertex path one of the two middle vertices). Now consider the unique paths $P_1,\ldots, P_\ell$ from $v$ to the $\ell$ different leafs. Notice that every vertex in $T$ must be contained in one of these paths (this needs to be justified). Using this, you can obtain a lower bound on the length of $P$, do you see how?
Let me know, if you have further questions, or if something is incorrect. I hope it helps :)
